# Overriden XMLHttpRequest for cross-domain requests

Tags: javascript, cross-domain

I'm wondering if there is a JavaScript library, which overrides `XMLHttpRequest` and allows to transparently handle all cross-domain requests and seamlessly forward them over my same-origin server-side proxy.

What I want is to have a common solution, which could be used together with **any** JavaScript library to make cross-domain requests (e.g. with cross-domain `jQuery.ajax()`).

Are there any drawbacks to use such library (security problems, HTTPS access, etc.)?

**Update:**

If such library is  already created by someone, than I just do not want to reinvent the wheel and handle all corner cases again.

Comment: Such a library would need to include the server-side script, or at least define its interface.

Comment: I've never seen a library that does overwrite native functions to alter their (standard) behaviour

Comment: @JanDvorak Sure, I am ready to add everything to the server side, especially if it is in Java.

Comment: @Bergi What about "extend", is that a better word for "alter"?

Comment: I believe such a library could be written, but I don't think it already exists.

Comment: @JanDvorak: Even extensions of the standardized behaviour are seldom implemented in the same place as the original functionality. I'm not sure what the OP exactly means by "transparent", just passing external URLs into `XMLHttpRequest` does not sound like a good idea. jQuery for example would not work well with that as it checks for cross-domain urls itself before calling XHR.

Comment: @Bergi: AFAIK, jQuery works pretty well with cross-domain calls. As an example, jQuery is widely used in PhoneGap applications, where same-origin policy could be disabled. I iust tried to run Chrome with `--disable-web-security` flag, and [this jQuery cross-domain example](http://jsbin.com/etamiy/1/edit) works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just need to redirect every request to a specific proxy you could simply write it yourself, something in the lines of

```
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
var newOpen = function(args) {
   //overwrite arguments changing the original url to the proxy one, 
   //and add a parameter/header to send the original url to the proxy
   this.oldOpen(args);    
}
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = newOpen;
```

Since the proxy is in the same domain (if you want to allow x-domain proxy requests, just add the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header), it will not be sent any cookie of the remote domain (you won't have them anyway, since x-domains cookies are blocked - as long as you don't enter the field with the header Access-Control-Allow-Credentials).

Some security implications are rather obvious:

- you are proxying the request, and as such the proxy itself will have access to everything, regardless of the encryption
- HTTPS handling will be demanded to the proxy (if the remote url is secure) and the client will not be able to (or, on the other hand, will not need to, if demanded to the proxy) directly verify the server certificates

A more complex (same domain, to fully support cookies) proxy implementation could even provide basic session handling for cross domain requests rewriting the headers:

1. Client requests *www.remotedomain.com/querystring* from *www.mydomain.com* without cookies
2. Request is rewritten as *proxy.mydomain.com/www.remotedomain.com/querystring*
3. The proxy makes a request to *www.remotedomain.com/querystring* which responds with the header

   ***Set-Cookie: name=value; path=/; expires Mon, 31-Dec-2012 23:59:59 GMT***
4. The client receive the response back with the header

   ***Set-Cookie: name=value; path=/www.remotedomain.com; expires Mon, 31-Dec-2012 23:59:59 GMT***
5. On the next request the client will send the cookie, and the proxy will just forward them to the remote service

But I'm probably digressing too much. :)

Comment: Actually, the question is about a proxy in **the same domain**. But with the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, your solution becomes even more interesting.

Answer (score 0):

I will not use JS for this kind of needs... Just make all your AJAX calls to a PHP file (or whatever) on your server that acts as a proxy.

It only needs to receive the url you want to call, POST or GET parameters and then make a cURL to the external server.

In return it will print the output of the cURL request.