# Cross domain request using XMLHttpRequest does not work but it works by JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, xmlhttprequest, cross-domain

I have the following code that gets "XMLHttpRequest cannot load due to access control checks." error:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.withCredentials = false;
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
              alert(xhr.responseText);}}
        xhr.open('GET', 'http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?', true);
        xhr.send(null);
```

But if I use jquery as follows, it works:

```
$.getJSON('http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=?', function(data) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
        alert(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));});
```

Is there a way to use XMLHttpRequest instead of Jquery to get the same result? From previous questions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20099792/cross-domain-request-with-xmlhttprequest-and-paypal), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3362474/jquery-ajax-fails-in-ie-on-cross-domain-calls), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17874730/how-to-make-cross-domain-request), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14664813/overriden-xmlhttprequest-for-cross-domain-requests), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819965/is-it-possible-to-use-xmlhttprequest-cross-domain)(the same question but not answered), 6, 7, 8, what I found is that using XMLHttpRequest we cannot do it? as the questions are very old, I would like to know if this is true?

Comment: becuase JSON**P** doesn't use XHR, it uses a `<script>` tag - look at the result of entering `http://gd.geobytes.com/GetCityDetails?callback=someRandomText` in your browser

Comment: can you explain more plz? thanks

Comment: JSONP is described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)